# The icon is hidden behind the background - CSS

Tags: css

I am a beginner and cannot find the answer. What am I doing wrong? The phone icon is hidden behind a white background. The setting is fine, but I want the icon to be on the front, followed by border and color.

```css
.phone-icon {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 15%;
    margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<img class="phone-icon" 
alt="Phone number" 
src="images/phone.png">
</img>
<span class="phone-number">
+00 12 34 56 789
</span>
```

Comment: I tried it in codepen and it works, the icon showed up, can you post a picture of your problem?

Comment: Same, are you saying that perhaps the icon you're using is white on a white background and you just can't see it?

Comment: It looks like this: https://gyazo.com/15e26357c05b0fba9643f25469ea4cd3 The black icon is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

LGTM!

I took a screenshot of you code snippet when it is run and added your icon as img src.

[image: I took a screenshot of you code snippet when it is run and added your icon as img src.]

Comment: It looks like this: gyazo.com/15e26357c05b0fba9643f25469ea4cd3 The black icon is not visible. :/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is : you're giving the color of white to your image by writing :  `background-color : white`.
Try to envelop your image with a `<div>` and give the white color to this div.
like this :

```html
<div class="white-div">
   <img class="phone-icon" 
   alt="Phone number" 
   src="images/phone.png">
   </img>
   <span class="phone-number">
   +00 12 34 56 789
  </span>
</div>
```

```css
.phone-icon {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 15%;
    margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.white-div {
   background-color : white;
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. : /